# Datadog event monitor aggregation

Tags: events, datadog

I have created a Multi alert event monitor

```
events('sources:rds event_source:db-instance').by('dbinstanceidentifier').rollup('count').last('1d') >= 1
```

I wanted it to be aggregated by "dbinstanceidentifier" but it shows the accumulative count for "* (Entire Infrastructure)". Basically it doesn't see any groups. But I can see them in the infrastructure. Is it a problem of datadog? May be it's only available in a kind of "premium" subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried with this query which is similar to yours:

```
events('sources:rds priority:all tags:event_source:db-instance').by('dbinstanceidentifier').rollup('count').last('1d') > 1
```

[image]

And this seems to give me a count by `dbinstanceidentifier` results.

Do you have more information to provide? Maybe an event list and a monitor result screenshot?

[image]

Comment: I recreated the monitor and it works now. It's mystery, I think it was because of the insufficient initial data